# Outlook Add-In Crashes or Your server administrator has limited the number of items you can open simultaneously

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I have created a simple Outlook Add-in for copying contacts from one folder to another.(~5000 contacts)

Why I need this? There is a weird way for creating a public address book as described [here](https://www.cogmotive.com/blog/office-365-tips/create-a-company-shared-contacts-folder-in-office-365).

So why not copy all the contacts in the public folder? I want my team to have a shared addressbook with my contacts but with only Fullname and emails as information.

I have added a toolbar with two Buttons. Choose folders and Synchronize.

My Problem is that when running Synchronization after a while I get

> Your server administrator has limited the number of items you can open simultaneously. Try closing messages you have opened or removing attachments and images from unsent messages you are composing.

I used `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` in every Object, tried to add some delay between Add. But still get the same error.

Then I found a post here in StackOverflow saying to add `GC.Collect` that stopped the error above but the Outlook always **crashes** at the end of Synchronizing and sometimes at the middle of it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Synchronize Code

```
 private Task SynchronizeContactsSync()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            if (!synchronizing)
            {
                synchronizing = true;

                Outlook.Folder toFolder = null;
                Outlook.Folder fromFolder = null;
                try
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tEntryID) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tStoreID) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fStoreID) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tEntryID))
                    {
                        toFolder = Application.Session.GetFolderFromID(tEntryID, tStoreID) as Outlook.Folder;
                        fromFolder = Application.Session.GetFolderFromID(fEntryID, fStoreID) as Outlook.Folder;
                    }

                    if (toFolder != null && fromFolder != null)
                    {
                        toFolder.InAppFolderSyncObject = false;
                        int currentItem = 0;


                        int itemCount = fromFolder.Items.Count;

                        //I dont want to use foreach because it keeps reference of each object until is done
                        //I cast it to list because i cant use for statement with fromFolder.Items

                        List<Outlook.ContactItem> items = fromFolder.Items.Cast<Outlook.ContactItem>().ToList(); ;

                        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
                        {

                            //await Task.Delay(33);
                            await addContactSync(items[i], toFolder);
                            if (items[i] != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(items[i]);
                            GC.Collect();
                            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                            GC.Collect();
                            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                            currentItem++;
                            syncText = "Synchronize progress " + currentItem + " of " + itemCount;
                        }

                        synchronizing = false;
                        syncText = "No Synchronize in progress";



                    }
                    MessageBox.Show("Done.", "Synchronize", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    if (toFolder != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(toFolder);
                    if (fromFolder != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(fromFolder);
                    toFolder.InAppFolderSyncObject = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (toFolder != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(toFolder);
                    if (fromFolder != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(fromFolder);
                    toFolder.InAppFolderSyncObject = true;
                    synchronizing = false;
                    syncText = "No Synchronize in progress";
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Synchronize", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Check you settings or please wait for the synchronization to finish.", "Synchronize", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        });
    }



    private Task addContactSync(Outlook.ContactItem item, Outlook.Folder toFolder)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            try
            {

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Email1Address))
                {
                    string filter = "[FullName] = '" + item.FullName + "'";// "[NickName] = '" + item.NickName + "' or [Email1Address] = '" + item.Email1Address + "' or 

                    Outlook.ContactItem matches = (Outlook.ContactItem)toFolder.Items.Find(filter);
                    if (matches == null)
                    {
                        Outlook.ContactItem contact = toFolder.Items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olContactItem);
                        contact.FullName = item.FullName;
                        contact.NickName = item.NickName;
                        contact.Email1Address = item.Email1Address;
                        contact.Email2Address = item.Email2Address;
                        contact.Save();
                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(contact);
                        itemSyncCount++;
                        lastItemSync = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        matches.Email1Address = item.Email1Address;
                        matches.Email2Address = item.Email2Address;
                        matches.Save();
                        itemSyncCount++;
                        lastItemSync = DateTime.Now;
                    }

                    if (item != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
                    if (matches != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(matches);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Contact", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use any LINQ statements against Outlook collections. Or you will trap into such situations. For example:

```
 List<Outlook.ContactItem> items = fromFolder.Items.Cast<Outlook.ContactItem>().ToList(); ;
```

The line of code creates a new COM object for each item in the folder simultaneously. Instead, you can iterate over all items in the folder in the *for* loop and release objects instantly by using the `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` method.

```
 Outlook.Items items = fromFolder.Items;
 for (int i = 1; i <= items.Count; i++)
 {
     object item = items[i];
     Outlook.ContactItem contact = item as Outlook.ContactItem;
     if (contact != null) //can also have DistListItem objects
     {
         ...
         Marshal.ReleaseComObject(contact); contact = null;
     }
     Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item); item = null;
 }
```

Use [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx) to release an Outlook object when you have finished using it. This is particularly important if your add-in attempts to enumerate more than 256 Outlook items in a collection that is stored on a Microsoft Exchange Server. If you do not release these objects in a timely manner, you can reach the limit imposed by Exchange on the maximum number of items opened at any one time. Then set a variable to Nothing in Visual Basic (null in C#) to release the reference to the object. Read more about that in the [Systematically Releasing Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb623945%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

Also note that the `as` operator in .Net creates an extra reference to the object that must be released.

Comment: I cant do 
`for (int i = 0; i < fromFolder.Items.Count; i++)
{
 fromFolder.Items[i] //Throws error
}` Also please read all the Question.

Comment: I was able to avoid the error by using Eugene's " Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);"  specifically,  I put that line of code directly after my function that pulls the MailItem properties (i.e. when I'm done with the MailItem)

Answer (score 0):

I will double confirm, Eugen solution above works. I had a different bug because of which I was still getting the LIMIT error

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++)
{
            MailItem item = items[i];
            if (item.ReceivedTime > np_start_time && item.ReceivedTime < np_end_time)
            {
                String subject = item.Subject;
                temp_msg.EmailFrom = item.SenderEmailAddress;
                temp_msg.EmailSubjectLine = item.Subject;
                temp_msg.EmailTimeStamp = item.ReceivedTime;
                temp_msg.EmailBody = item.Body;


                OL_messages.Add(temp_msg);
                
            // Incorrect way - only objects in the if-clause are released
            // System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
            // item = null;

            }

            // Correct - Place at the end of the loop
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item);
            item = null; 
            
 }
```